# Query-Driven Modelling and Big Data

Tags: cassandra

I was watching one of the Cassandra videos on DataSax Academy. One concept they talk a lot about is query driven modelling. This makes sense when you know your queries upfront like in the KillrVideo example.

However, in big data cases, I hope I am not the only one to think that we barely know what kind of queries analysts will perform on the data 5 months or one year down the road.

If this is the case, what are the best practices for storing your data? My guess is that for advanced querying of such data, you likely will end up loading your data into Spark. But what do I have to consider at storage time to avoid operational troubles and troubles at retrieval time? What retrieval approaches are less problematic?

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra is also a database for analytics use cases, but not always for Ad-Hoc Analaytics (Only one report and this query will never perform again stuff).

For this use cases is a hadoop cluster a better option for your. (Maybe parquete on hadoop) If you see that queries will perform over and over again, Cassandra is your friend. Generally you can use Cassandra for 50 to 70% of your use cases. With column keys and secondary indizies you can perform really a wide spectrum of queries. Go to your Analytics Guys and ask them what they need. Then: Create your tables :)

Answer (score 0):

Datastax has a course on doing [analysis on Cassandra with Apache Spark](https://academy.datastax.com/courses/getting-started-apache-spark).